# Perl ::To find the no of occurenaces and max min value

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl, perl-data-structures

Please help me to find the no of occurrences in file. also to find the max and min values. Im able to find the no of occurrences.

file

```
SQL :: select * from person ...etc , Time Taken :: 30 
SQL :: select * from emp ...etc , Time Taken :: 5 
SQL :: select * from home ...etc , Time Taken :: 20 
SQL :: select * from emp ...etc , Time Taken :: 30 
SQL :: select * from person ...etc , Time Taken :: 10 
SQL :: select * from home ...etc , Time Taken :: 20 
SQL :: select * from person ...etc , Time Taken :: 50
```

output should be`enter code here`

```
SQL                    No of occu        total Min  Max 
select * from person    3                  90   10   50 
select * from emp       2                  35    5   30
```

Comment: Your question could do with a bit more detail. Like - why is this a perl question, rather than a SQL question, for starters.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: Im reading this from file... Im generating report like each SQLs how mach time taking and min , max time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


# sql -> {times, min, max}
my $data = {};
while (<>) {
    if (m{SQL.*?(select.*?\.\.\.).*?Taken\s\:\:\s(\d+)}xmsi) {
        my ($sql, $time) = ($1, $2);
        my $times = $data->{$sql}->{times} || 0;
        my $min = $data->{$sql}->{min} || $time;
        my $max = $data->{$sql}->{max} || $time;
        $max = $time if $time > $max;
        $min = $time if $time < $min;
        $times++;

        $data->{$sql}->{min} = $min;
        $data->{$sql}->{max} = $max;
        $data->{$sql}->{times} = $times;
    }
}

print "SQL No of occu total Min Max\n";
foreach my $sql(sort keys %{$data}) {
    print "$sql $data->{$sql}->{times} total $data->{$sql}->{min} $data->{$sql}->{max}\n";
}
```

running:

```
stat.pl <your data file>
```

add total yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works. but im having issue with  output in CSV..

if the column(SQLs) contains any comma (,) or question mark (?) then its split-ed with many columns. Tried Encoding => 'base64' in the attachments. but still im facing the same issue. please suggest.

Comment: You can use \' to escape comma, it's difficult to parse that csv, use '|' may be better. Using base64 is a better way. For data line "sql_in_base64,time", my ($sql_base64, $time) = split(/,/, $_); $sql = decodebase64($sql_base64);